# how to get url html contents to string in java

Tags: java, html, url, file-io

I have a html file stored on the server. I have the URL path something like this: `<https://localhost:9443/genesis/Receipt/Receipt.html >`

I want to read the contents of this html file which would contain tags, from the url i.e. the source code of the html file.

How am I supposed to do this? This is a server side code and can't have a browser object and I am not sure using a URLConnection would be a good option.

What should be the best solution now?

Comment: `String content = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(new Url("https://localhost:9443/genesis/Receipt/Receipt.html"), "utf8");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved it using spring 
added the bean to the spring config file

```
  <bean id = "receiptTemplate" class="org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource">
    <constructor-arg value="/WEB-INF/Receipt/Receipt.html"></constructor-arg>
  </bean>
```

then read it in my method

```
        // read the file into a resource
        ClassPathResource fileResource =
            (ClassPathResource)context.getApplicationContext().getBean("receiptTemplate");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileResource.getFile()));
        String line;
        StringBuffer sb =
            new StringBuffer();

        // read contents line by line and store in the string
        while ((line =
            br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        br.close();
        return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 14):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
 
public class URLContent {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // get URL content
            
            String a = "http://localhost:8080//TestWeb/index.jsp";
            URL url = new URL(a);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
 
            // open the stream and put it into BufferedReader
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                               new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
 
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }
            br.close();
 
            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how about on remote site url? The problem actually on script location

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

//...

URL url = new URL("https://localhost:9443/genesis/Receipt/Receipt.html");
url.openConnection();
InputStream reader = url.openStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

For exemple :

```
        URL url = new URL("https://localhost:9443/genesis/Receipt/Receipt.html");
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String l;
        while ((l=in.readLine())!=null) {
            System.out.println(l);
        }
```

You could use the inputstream in other ways, not just printing it.

Of course if you have the path to the local file, you can also do

```
  InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(yourPath));
```

Comment: this is a server side code and I was refraining from using URLConnection. Not sure if it would be a good approach. What do you reckon?

Comment: This is not server side code, why are you refraining from using URLConnection?

Comment: If you know where are your files locally, you also can use `FileInputStream` (see extended answer).

Comment: the code I am working on is a server side code. I am actually writing a service which would read the receipt template, also stored on the web server(and available through the url) and process it.

Comment: If the files you are looking for are not on your server, I don't see any other way besides connecting to the URL. However, as mentioned above, if the files are local you can use a regular `FileInputStream`.

Comment: The file is on a web server and the code I am working on would also be deployed on the webserver. Authentication and connection management won't be an issue. Only thing is I am not able to read the contents. I am trying the URLConnection method but I am not sure it would be the best approach, though I am not so sure of that as well

Comment: @PeyushGoel: If the files are local you should be able to use `FileInputStream`, provided you have the full path.

Comment: url connection is throwing certification exception.... probably this is a development environment and won't occur in a production environment but i should have a better approach. Is there a way to read it in a file, fileReader, fileInputStream? remember I have a url to the html file

Comment: You need to know where is the root of your html files so that you can use FileInputStream.

Comment: From the URL, you can read it with URLConnection. But it's more advisable to determine where are your files and read it using FileInputStream.

Comment: is there a way to do it using spring config?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way in my opinion is to use `IOUtils`

```
import com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils;
...

String uri = "https://localhost:9443/genesis/Receipt/Receipt.html";
String fileContents = IOUtils.toString(new URL(uri).openStream());
System.out.println(fileContents);
```