# Getting URL contents

Tags: java, http, url

I've got a server application that responds to HTTP GET requests with an XML response. I'm having trouble making a small Java app to get the contents of this response. Every kind of read I try on the response, or `getContent()`, or whathaveyou returns nothing.

I first tried the examples listed here:
[how to get url html contents to string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087163/how-to-get-url-html-contents-to-string-in-java)

But those use the deprecated readLine() method of InputStream. In the cases above, `read()`/`available()` seem to always indicate there's nothing to read (they return -1 and 0, respectively), but give a 200 response code.

Any other URL (http://www.google.com/humans.txt, for example) works fine.

So, I found a more relevant link here:
[How to read XML response from a URL in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310139/how-to-read-xml-response-from-a-url-in-java)

Which gave me:

```
String urlString = new String("http://homeserver/ampache/server/xml.server.php?action=handshake&auth=" + hash + "&timestamp=" + timestamp + "&version=3600013&user=" + user");
DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new URL(urlString).openStream());
System.out.println(doc.toString());
```

But it looks like I have the same problem:

```
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end of file.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
```

Then I tried Apache's HTTPClient, which also returned zilch in the body but with a 200 response code.

The URL is my Ampache installation. It's their [XML API](http://ampache.org/wiki/xmlapi): `http://homeserver/ampache/server/xml.server.php?action=handshake&auth...`. This URL works fine from the browser, and returns what I'm expecting at this point:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
    <error code="403"><![CDATA[Unauthorized access attempt to API - ACL Error]]>
</error>
</root>
```

Comment: Can you please show some code to us? Without code it is difficult to say what you do wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Ampache URL was malformed, or there is a bug in Ampache's API. The request works fine for `http://homeserver/ampache/server/xml.server.php?action=handshake`, but not the full on URL with authentication details.